# Next and previous linking in JavaScript image gallery not working

Tags: javascript, navigation, image-gallery

I need to have multiple galleries on the same page (with captions), and have been trying to implement this javascript, but I cannot get the next | previous links to work for either gallery. New to javascript - any suggestions?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/astHh/11/

HTML:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
  <!--  Place the first image here  -->
  <img src="http://www.cool-smileys.com/images/out11.jpg" id="mypic" name="mypic" alt="information" border="0" height="150" width="200">
  <br>
  <!--  Place the text for the first image here  --><div id="burns">Caption one</div>
  <p>
  <a href="#" onclick="S2.UpDown(-1); return false;">&laquo; Previous</a> |
  <a href="#" onclick="S2.UpDown(1); return false;"> Next &raquo;</a>
</div>

<p>

<div style="text-align: center">
  <!--  Place the first image here  -->
  <img src="http://www.cool-smileys.com/images/out13.jpg" id="mypic2" name="mypic2" alt="information" border="0" height="150" width="200">
  <br>
  <!--  Place the text for the first image here  --> <div id="burns2">Caption two</div>
  <p>
  <a href="#" onclick="S2.UpDown(-1); return false;">&laquo; Previous</a> |
  <a href="#" onclick="S2.UpDown(1); return false;"> Next &raquo;</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function SimpleSlideShow(o){
 this.img=document.getElementById(o.ImageID);
 this.txt=document.getElementById(o.TextID);
 this.ary=o.Array||[];
 this.cnt=0;
}

SimpleSlideShow.prototype.UpDown=function(ud){
  this.cnt+=ud;
  this.cnt=this.cnt<0?this.ary.length-1:this.cnt==this.ary.length?0:this.cnt;
  if (this.ary[this.cnt]){
   if (this.img&&this.ary[this.cnt][0]){
    this.img.src=this.ary[this.cnt][0];
    this.img.alt=this.ary[this.cnt][1];
   }
   if (this.txt){
    this.txt.innerHTML=this.ary[this.cnt][2]||'';
   }
  }
 }

S1=new SimpleSlideShow({
 ImageID:'mypic',
 TextID:'burns',
 Array:[
  ['http://www.cool-smileys.com/images/out11.jpg,' 'Caption one', 'The beautiful mountains'],
  ['http://www.cool-smileys.com/images/out10.jpg','Caption two','The crystal clear lake'],

]
});

S2=new SimpleSlideShow({
 ImageID:'mypic2',
 TextID:'burns2',
 Array:[
  ['http://www.cool-smileys.com/images/out13.jpg','caption one', 'The beautiful mountains'],
  ['http://www.cool-smileys.com/images/out12.jpg','caption two','The lonesome, barren tree']
]
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple syntax errors in your javascript:

Remove from the script pane:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

Within your definition of "S1", you're missing a comma (just before 'Caption one'):

```
S1=new SimpleSlideShow({
    ImageID:'mypic',
    TextID:'burns',
    Array:[
        ['http://www.cool-smileys.com/images/out11.jpg,','Caption one', 'The beautiful mountains'],
        ['http://www.cool-smileys.com/images/out10.jpg','Caption two','The crystal clear lake'],
    ]
});
```

Then in the HTML pane, you should update the first set prev/next links to target S1 instead of S2.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/astHh/12/

Comment: Man, really should have looked to see if it was answered before I did the exact same thing as you. Nice work!

Comment: Thanks! This works great in the fiddle, it still doesn't work when I put it into dreamweaver and preview it in safari/firefox. Any thoughts as to why? I don't have any additional javascript.

Comment: Are any errors thrown? Are you retaining the <script> tags in outside of the fiddle? (you should be)

Comment: Yes I have the <script type="text/javascript"> tag back in, doesn't prompt any errors just opens in the browser, but neither of the previous/next links function at all.

Comment: Works if i put the <script> inside the <body> tag.

Comment: That's because you aren't waiting for a load/domready event before executing your script. So then getElementById isn't able to find dom elements that don't exist yet.